# How do I load form data based on variable?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to load a form when a button is clicked.  The form should show a label based on which button is clicked.  When I run the code below everything works correctly EXCEPT after I go thru the buttons the variable from the last button is the only one that displays no matter what I click.

Form1

```
    Public Class MainScreen
        Public RebootServer As Integer = 0
        Public StartServer As Integer = 0
        Public StopServer As Integer = 0
        Public CurrentServerInfo As Integer = 0

        Private Sub RebootServerMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RebootServerMenuItem.Click
            RebootServer = 1
            CurrentConnectionForm.Show()
        End Sub

        Private Sub StartServerMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartServerMenuItem.Click
            StartServer = 1
            CurrentConnectionForm.Show()

        End Sub

        Private Sub StopServerMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StopServerMenuItem.Click
            StopServer = 1
            CurrentConnectionForm.Show()

        End Sub

        Private Sub ConnectionInfoMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ConnectionInfoMenuItem.Click
            CurrentServerInfo = 1
            CurrentConnectionForm.Show()

        End Sub
    End Class
```

Form2

```
    Public Class CurrentConnectionForm

        Dim RebootServer As Integer = MainScreen.RebootServer
        Dim StartServer As Integer = MainScreen.StartServer
        Dim StopServer As Integer = MainScreen.StopServer
        Dim CurrentServerInfo As Integer = MainScreen.CurrentServerInfo

        Private Sub CurrentConnectionForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


            If RebootServer = 1 Then
                RebootServerLabel.Visible = True
                StartServerLabel.Visible = False
                StopServerLabel.Visible = False
                ConnectionInfoLabel.Visible = False
            End If
            If StartServer = 1 Then
                RebootServerLabel.Visible = False
                StartServerLabel.Visible = True
                StopServerLabel.Visible = False
                ConnectionInfoLabel.Visible = False
            End If
            If StopServer = 1 Then
                RebootServerLabel.Visible = False
                StartServerLabel.Visible = False
                StopServerLabel.Visible = True
                ConnectionInfoLabel.Visible = False
            End If
            If CurrentServerInfo = 1 Then
                RebootServerLabel.Visible = False
                StartServerLabel.Visible = False
                StopServerLabel.Visible = False
                ConnectionInfoLabel.Visible = True
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

I have tried changing the if statements to if/else if, and rearranging when the variables were called.

When I click reboot server on form1 I want form2 to load and display the label for rebooting server, same for start, stop and connection info.

Comment: Think you need to review your logic a little, but anyway.  Don't see anywhere where you are *Unsetting* the button variables.  That will be why it looks like the last one is clicked all the time

Comment: A form only loads once.  Form2 just shouldn't have access to Form1 like that.  Create public methods on your Form2 for RebootServer, StartServer, etc.  Form1 should have a reference to Form2 by it's declaration: `Private cForm As New CurrentConnectionForm()`.  Then you can just reference things like: `cForm.RebootServer()` etc.

Comment: @Hursey Thanks.  I redid the way I was sending and pulling the variable and it fixed it.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for the reply.  I started to do this and ended up sending the info and little different which fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an `Enum` to hold the four different states, then declared a `Shared` variable of that type:

```
Public Class MainScreen

    Public Enum ServerTypeEnum
        RebootServer
        StartServer
        StopServer
        CurrentServerInfo
    End Enum

    Public Shared ServerType As ServerTypeEnum

    Private Sub RebootServerMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RebootServerMenuItem.Click
        ServerType = ServerTypeEnum.RebootServer
        CurrentConnectionForm.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartServerMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartServerMenuItem.Click
        ServerType = ServerTypeEnum.StartServer
        CurrentConnectionForm.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StopServerMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StopServerMenuItem.Click
        ServerType = ServerTypeEnum.StopServer
        CurrentConnectionForm.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ConnectionInfoMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ConnectionInfoMenuItem.Click
        ServerType = ServerTypeEnum.CurrentServerInfo
        CurrentConnectionForm.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now your second form simply becomes:

```
Public Class CurrentConnectionForm

    Private Sub CurrentConnectionForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RebootServerLabel.Visible = (MainScreen.ServerType = MainScreen.ServerTypeEnum.RebootServer)
        StartServerLabel.Visible = (MainScreen.ServerType = MainScreen.ServerTypeEnum.StartServer)
        StopServerLabel.Visible = (MainScreen.ServerType = MainScreen.ServerTypeEnum.StopServer)
        ConnectionInfoLabel.Visible = (MainScreen.ServerType = MainScreen.ServerTypeEnum.CurrentServerInfo)
    End Sub

End Class
```